# Split a file into multiple files, using the first X positions of a line, using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, split

I have a large text file, containing up to 2300 sections.
Each section begins, one line before, "PAGE   1"
The page number is at very end of the line,

Example:

```
T5271-AX1   TITLE                             DATE
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   1
LINE1
LINE2                                
T5271-AX1   TITLE                             PAGE   2
LINE3
LINE4
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   3
LINE5
T5271-BX1                                     DATE
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   1
LINE1
```

The file up to 2300 sections and each section can have several hundred pages, but sections always has "PAGE   1" at the end of the line.

The name of the file is contained in the first string of 9-15 characters on the line above "PAGE   1"

I want to split the file at "PAGE   1" and used the 9-15 characters at the name of the output file.

In my example the end result would be two files:

```
T5271-AX1
T5271-BX1
```

I can easily locate the page number and the title, but I don't know how to split the file and output it into a new file, until the the the next occurance of "PAGE  1".

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is no `PAGE 1` in your input ...

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/ PAGE   1$/ {
    close(out)
    split(prev,p)
    out = p[1]
}
NR > 1 { print prev > out }
{ prev = $0 }
END { print prev > out }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

```
$ head T*
==> T5271-AX1 <==
T5271-AX1   TITLE                             DATE
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   1
LINE1
LINE2
T5271-AX1   TITLE                             PAGE   2
LINE3
LINE4
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   3
LINE5

==> T5271-BX1 <==
T5271-BX1                                     DATE
     SUB TITLE                                PAGE   1
LINE1
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `csplit` , for *context* split, will do what you are asking for.

```
csplit -sz file '/ PAGE   1$/-1' '{*}'
for  f in xx*;do
  mv -f -- "$f" "$(< "$f" head -n1 | cut -f1 -d" ")"
done
```